# App in SharePoint 2013 asking for user and pasword

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013

I have an app that was created in Visual Studio 2013, when i deploy it, it gets installed, i can see the link in my Dev site, but when I try to access it, the app keeps asking me for Username and password, I've tried several users/passwords and even though i have permissions it still doesn't let me do anything, Please advise.

Comment: Thank you, I ve tried all of those steps, the only one I hadn't was the disableing the loopback check.

Comment: The disabling the loopback check helped me out with this issue ;)

Comment: I have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Disable Loopback Check**

1. Click on `Start` -> `Run` and type `regedit`
2. Locate the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa`
3. Right click on this key and choose New > `DWord` Value
4. Name this one `DisableLoopbackCheck1
5. Double-click then on it and type the value `1`
6. Reboot your server.

Note - Create 32 bit DWORD